# Should I use ory kratos or Ory hydra

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, microservices, identity-management

We are redesigning our system , and moving from monolith to microservice one by one.

For that matter we have created a service that will authenticate the user in both legacy and the new app. This service will handle the authentication ( and importation of the users ) logic , but I don't want to implements all the authentication processes from scratch.
So I was considering using kratos/hydra.
When I checked the documentation there is two ways to implement authentication process :

1. Either by using the browser
2. Or by using the API

For my use case I want to use the API for the main reason that it is more decoupled from the frontend, so my microservice won't be hold configurations for another service that it doesn't use. But I'm confront with two issues :

1. First the current API doesn't handle OIC authentication out of the box , and some were suggesting that I should use hydra. But I don't know how conceptually it is supposed to be used.
2. Second, the API authentication support only session authentication , and I want to have more flexibility upon this.

So my question is :
Am I supposed to use Kratos , Hydra or both for this , and how I am supposed to deal with this issues ?